# How to configure Maven2 to publish to Artifactory?

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, publish

Currently I have a Maven2 project that builds a JAR when you run:

```
mvn clean package
```

I need to now tweak the `pom.xml` to publish this JAR (`myapp.jar`) to an Artifactory server running at:

```
http://myartifactory/artifactory/simple/myorg/myapp/0.1
```

I tried adding a `<repositories>` element to my `pom.xml` but nothing is being published with this config:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>myartifactory</id>
        <url>http://myartifactory/artifactory/simple/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Any ideas as to how I could get publishing to work?  For simplicity's sake, pretend that this Artifactory repo is authenticated to accept publishes/writes from a user with a `username=foo` and `password=bar`.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what errors you're seeing. You may just need a settings.xml file in your ~/.m2 directory containing credentials to access that server.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan (+1) - I was rushing when creating this question and didn't explain the situation accurately (see my edits). No errors per se, just not publishing. If this config looks good to you (and isn't missing anything or have anything misconfigured) then can you point me in the direction (or provide as an answer) a `settings.xml` example that has the correct user creds? Thanks again!

Comment: the short answer, run `mvn deploy`, of course after adding the artifactory details (user/password/servers) inside your `setting.xml` file

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have two options (please note that the later is the recommended one):

**Add `DistributionManagement` part to your pom and `server` part to your `settings.xml`**

1. Let's say you want to deploy to libs-snapshot-local repository. In this case you need to go to the tree browser in Artifactory, focus on the repository level, copy the `Distribution Management` snippet and paste it in your `pom.xml`:
   [image: Distribution Managment]
2. Next, you need to tell maven the credentials. For that, click on your username in the top right corner, enter your password to unlock the screen, copy the `server` tag from `Maven Settings` panel:
   [image]
   This one you paste in your `settings.xml`. Don't forget to replace the ${server-id} with the real server id (the one you have in Distribution Management now).
3. Now, just run `mvn deploy` and enjoy.

---

**Working with Maven Artifactory Plugin:**

1. Add the relevant `<plugin>` part as described in the [wiki](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) to your `pom.xml`. It includes both the target repository and the credentials (please use external credentials source, like environment variables or system properties).
2. Run `mvn deploy` and enjoy not only the deployment to Artifactory, but also additional features as described below.

Additional features of Artifactory Maven Plugin (on top of regular Maven deployment):

1. Allow adding [custom properties](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Properties) to the deployed files
2. Provide the build bill of materials (the buildInfo), allowing [Build Integration](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration) with any build server (even those not supported by JFrog) or even with standalone builds (without build server at all).

Comment: Thanks @JBaruch (+1) - will running `mvn deploy` also run `mvn clean package` under the hood? Thanks again for such a great answer!

Comment: Please read a bit about [Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). `install` runs `package`, but does not run `clean` (it's a different lifecycle).

If you find the answer correct, please accept it.

Comment: Thanks again @JBaruch (+1) - one last followup: so it seems like I could run `mvn clean`, and *then* `mvn deploy` and get the benefits of both clean and deploy, right? Thanks again!