# Can Jenkins be used to store project jar at some remote location after build

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, maven-install-plugin

For my project I need to store jar after each build at some other url. Is there a way to get it done by Jenkins job.

I am quite new to jenkins.

Comment: Yes, of course that is possible have a look at [Publish Over SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin).

Comment: Better use a repository manager like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva for such purposes...

Comment: I have an artifactory and i need to publish my jar to that artifactory only @khmarbaise... however dont kno how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good explanation on how to publish your artifact to a repository (best practice) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24135640/1309035). This is equivalent for Maven3 and Maven2.

The answer refers to Artifactory. Make sure to also take a look at Nexus and Archiva as [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) noted.

**tl;dr**

If using Artifactory, add the [Maven Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) to your pom.