# convert a jenkins artifactory post build step into a pipeline stage

Tags: java, maven, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I'm converting a Jenkins job which has been configured in the UI to one that is configured using a declarative pipeline script.

It's a maven built Java project with a post-build action that deploys to Artifactory

The build and test step is straightforward. we can take this UI

[image: the maven UI]

And convert it to a mvn command `sh "mvn clean install"`.

The config for the post build step is simple *in the UI*

[image: the post build artifactory UI]

This has three text boxes checked

1. deploy maven artifacts
2. filter excluded artifacts from build info (I don't think there are any though)
3. capture and publish build info

This generates and uploads a rich buildInfo.json and uploads the correct artifacts to our artifactory server.

I want to replace this with a pipeline step... reading this documentation https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax suggests that building maven jobs should be done by having the artifactory plugin run the maven commands. I'd like to avoid this because we don't do that currently *and* I'd eventually like to remove the need to store artifacts for this project on the server.

In the pom we would see

```
    <groupId>some.value</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.184</version>
```

I've got to a partially working script:

```
stage('publish common code to artifactory') {
          steps {
            rtUpload (
                  serverId: 'Artifactory',
                  spec: '''{
                        "files": [
                          {
                            "pattern": "applications/my-app/pom.xml",
                            "target": "libs-release-local"
                          }
                       ]
                  }''',

                  buildName: 'my-app',
                  buildNumber: env.GIT_HASH_VERSION
              )
              rtPublishBuildInfo (
                    serverId: "Artifactory",
                    buildName: 'my-app',
                    buildNumber: env.GIT_HASH_VERSION
                )
          }
        }
```

This publishes the pom to artifactory but where originally it would publish to `some/value/my-app/my-app-1.1.184.pom` my pipeline version publishes to the root as `/pom.xml`

Artifactory looks capable of reading info from the pom and using it to correctly place the artifacts without me having to write code but how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122382/how-to-configure-maven2-to-publish-to-artifactory

Comment: must be a permissions issue, we're on a different version of artifactory but when I view the page specified in that SO question I don't see the same info as the answer suggests

Comment: You can refer the below examples provided by JFrog
https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples

Create a pipeline Jenkins job and give the required details. Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

Example that may help someone:

```
  stage("deploy_mvn") {
                environment {
                    // Must define environmental variable for maven
                    MAVEN_HOME = '/usr/share/maven'
                }
                steps {
                    script {
                        def artserver = Artifactory.newServer url: 'http://example.com/artifactory', credentialsId: 'blahblah'
                        def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
                        rtMaven.resolver server: artserver, releaseRepo: 'my-repo', snapshotRepo: 'my-ss-repo'
                        rtMaven.deployer server: artserver, releaseRepo: 'my-local', snapshotRepo: 'my-snapshot-local'
                        rtMaven.deployer.artifactDeploymentPatterns.addInclude("*.pom").addInclude("*.war").addInclude("*.jar")
                        rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = true
                        def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install'
                    }
                }
            }
```