# Deploying artifacts built by maven to repository

Tags: java, artifactory, artifacts, maven-deploy-plugin, remote-repository

I want to deploy artifacts to remote repository. My current pom is configured to deploy a jar. I also have `.json` config file which gets created under target folder in my project along with `.jar` during the build.  I would like to deploy both `.jar` and `.json` to remote repository.

**Method 1 :** Added DistributionManagement part to my pom.xml and server part to my settings.xml as per below post and ran `mvn deploy`. This copied only `.jar` file to my remote repository.

[How to configure Maven2 to publish to Artifactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122382/how-to-configure-maven2-to-publish-to-artifactory/24135640#comment128299276_24135640)

**Method 2 :**
Was able to push both `.jar` and `.json` through command line goal using:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M2:deploy-file -Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy> \
-DrepositoryId=some.id \
-Dfile=my-project/target/.jar \
-DpomFile=my-project/pom.xml \
-Dfiles=my-project/target/test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,my-project/target/test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.json \
-Dclassifiers=debug,site \
-Dtypes=jar,json
```

But I'd like to do this outside the command line.
Please let me know if there is any way to update this in pom.xml and deploy both .json and .jar files to remote repository. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does maven even try to upload to your remote repository? Does it give an error? If it doesn't even try, then there is something wrong in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: In Method 1, I do not see any error. Only .`jar` file is getting uploaded to remote repository but not `.json`

Comment: Then I guess your `<DistributionManagement>` config section is not getting read by maven. Are you sure it's at the correct level in the xml? https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management

Comment: You added a repository under distributionmanagement too, right?

Comment: yes I did. 
```<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id></id>
            <url><URL></url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>some_id</id>
            <url><URL></url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to push .json file with `<build-helper-maven-plugin>`.  Link for reference: https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html